# Saving multiple instances of a related model (has_many)

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have a products table which in for each type of associate (another table) there is a price.

This brings me to the tables:

```
# product

# associate_types
## description

# associate_prices
## product_id
## associate_type_id
## price
```

Product's Model relations:

`'prices' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AssociatePrices', 'id_product')`

AssociatePrices:

```
'associateType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AssociateTypes', 'id_associate_type'),
```

Now, on the Product form I'm displaying all kinds of AssociateTypes in order to user fill in the prices for all the AssociateTypes, and I managed this pretty well: I'm fetching the associateTypes, the prices already inserted for this given product and then cross them.

In order to update/create those entries, I have the following code in Product's afterSave():

```
    if(isset($_POST['AssociatePrices'])) {
        $this->pricesDup = array(); // overwriting current price setting
        foreach ($_POST['AssociatePrices'] as $i => $price) {
            $this->pricesDup[$i] = AssociatePrices::model();
            $this->pricesDup[$i]->attributes = $price;
            $this->pricesDup[$i]->id_product = $this->id;
            $this->pricesDup[$i]->save(false);
        }
    }
```

`$this->pricesDup` is a property I just made out since I can't play with `$this->prices`.

What's happing, is that even if the save() method returns true, the database remains unchanged.

I've already read a lot of stuff from the yii framework forum but none of that stuff actually applied to my case. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

EDIT: the Products model has also a beforeSave() function but it's not related with this issue. Even though i'm posting (a part of) it here upon request.

```
/**
 * This function's mission is to handle the file upload.
 */ 
public function beforeSave() 
{
    parent::beforeSave();
    // File uploading
    if (is_object($this->image)) {
        $dir = PRODUCTS_FILES_PATH;

        $current = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getPost('currentImage');
        if (!empty($current))
            @unlink($dir.$current);

        $name = $this->image->name;
        $j = 1;
        while (file_exists($dir . $name)) {
            //....
        }
        $this->image->saveAs($dir.$name, true);
        $this->image = $name;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update v2.0**
Your new model instance is not correct.You didnt wrote the **new** keyword to initialize the model.

```
$this->pricesDup[$i] = AssociatePrices::model();
```

It must be:

```
  $this->pricesDup[$i] = new AssociatePrices;
```

**Update**
Create a new model instance so that it can be saved in database:

```
    $pricesDup = new PriceDup;</strike>
```

Did you forget to assign the attributes? like this:
`$model->attributes=$_POST['attributes'];`

Comment: Nope.
$this->pricesDup[$i]->attributes = $price;

$price comes from $_POST vars :)

Comment: So, Where is the new Model instance.Like:Check Updated Answer
did you have `beforeSave()` function in that controller? if yes then show us that also.

Comment: There is a `beforeSave` but it's not related with this issue (prices). Even though i'll post it. 
"Create a new model instance so that it can be saved in database" I'm doing that inside the foreach.

Comment: When you say "function in that controller" you mean model, right? :) Thanks

Comment: @LuísLopes function can be in controller or model.Anyway its not interfering to save.BTW Your new model instance is not corrected. Check the updated answer.

Comment: "Your new model instance is not corrected." You were right. Not it's working like a charm, thank you! :)